# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object with scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a custom downloader middleware as below:

```
class NewsCrawlerDownloaderMiddleware:
    # Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
    # scrapy acts as if the downloader middleware does not modify the
    # passed objects.

    def __init__(self):
        self.urls_visited = get_visited_urls()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Called for each request that goes through the downloader
        # middleware.

        # Must either:
        # - return None: continue processing this request
        # - or return a Response object
        # - or return a Request object
        # - or raise IgnoreRequest: process_exception() methods of
        #   installed downloader middleware will be called
        # Here we check if url has already been scraped,
        # if not process the requests
        if request.url in self.urls_visited:
            logging.info('url already scraped: %s', request.url)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
        else:
            # logging.info('new middleware url: %s', request.url)
            return request

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # Called with the response returned from the downloader.

        # Must either;
        # - return a Response object
        # - return a Request object
        # - or raise IgnoreRequest
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        # Called when a download handler or a process_request()
        # (from other downloader middleware) raises an exception.

        # Must either:
        # - return None: continue processing this exception
        # - return a Response object: stops process_exception() chain
        # - return a Request object: stops process_exception() chain
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

The above middleware gets already scraped urls from the database and checks if `request.url` has already been scraped or not.

My downloader middlewares in spider looks like this:

```
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'news_crawler.middlewares.NewsCrawlerDownloaderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
```

When I run the crawler it fails with the following error:

```
 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://arynews.tv/robots.txt>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Note it doesnot happen when I remove my `NewsCrawlerDownloaderMiddleware` and then it crawls just fine. I have been trying to look into this but have got no luck. Any ideas will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What does the `get_visited_urls()` function do under the hood?

I would expect a function in there somewhere calling itself often, with the recursive self-calling being tied to either an interaction it has with `'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware'`, or this list in general because it just trips on the first entry.

(I know this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet).

Comment: ```get_visited_urls()``` gets all scrapped urls from database

Comment: Right but how is it implemented? The error indicates that a function has called itself too often, but there doesn't seem to be any function in your code which does that. So to me it seems it must be somewhere in the implementation of  `get_visited_urls()`. 

Is `get_visisted_urls` a function from a 3rd party module with documentation available? In that case; have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: Could you post the entire error traceback? I think there should be more than just that line.

Comment: It could also be that particular URL. Does it work for other URLs?